# Botão aparece sobreposto

Tags: javascript, css, posicionamento

Estou a adicionar botoes para adiconar musicas aos favoritos, mas este botao so esta aparecer nas primeiras musicas, nao aparece nas outras abaixo, parece que os botoes estao sobrepostos... Mas nao encontro o problema... Estou a usar css e js...

CSS:

```
/* --- BOTOES PARA O SEE MORE --- */

    .option-btn1 {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline;
        top: 50px;
        z-index: 10000;
    }


    .option-btn1 .btn-add-fav i {
        position: relative;
        left: 40px;
        top: 165px;
        font-size: 200%;
        color: #000;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        z-index: 10000;
    }



    .option-btn1 .btn-add-fav i:hover {
        color: #74C8D2;
        z-index: 10000;
    }
```

JS:

```
$(".see-more-btn").click(function(){
            let singles=[];
            $(".div-pesquisa").hide();
            $("#more-music").show();
            $("#more-music .row h3").html("You searched for " + response.artists[0].name);
            $(".see-more-music").empty();
            $(".see-more-music").html('<li><button class="go-back-btn" type="button" name="button" id="your-playlist" onclick="backArtist()"><i class="ion-ios-arrow-back" ></i>GO BACK</button></li>');
            url="http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/"+ response.artists[0].id +"?inc=releases&fmt=json";
            url=encodeURI(url);
            //alert(url);
            $.get(url,function(response,status){
              if (status=='success') {
                for (result of response.releases) {
                  //alert(result.id);
                  var album = result.id;
                  let titulo = result.title;
                  url="http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release/"+album+"?inc=recordings+media&fmt=json";
                  url=encodeURI(url);
                  $.get(url,function(response,status){
                    if (status=='success') {
                      let aux=0;
                      for (music of response.media[0].tracks) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < singles.length; i++) {
                          if (singles[i]==music.title) {
                            aux=1;
                            break;
                          }
                        }
                        if (aux==1) {
                          break;
                        }else{
                          singles[i+1]=music.title;
                        }

                      $(".see-more-music").append($("<li>").append($("<figure>").addClass("music-img").append($("<div>").addClass("option-btn1").append($("<div>").addClass("btn-add-fav").append($("<i>").addClass("ion-ios-add").click(function(){
                        addFav(response.items[0].snippet.title);
                      })))).append($("<i>").addClass("ion-ios-play-circle")).append($("<div>").addClass("info-music").append($("<h6>").html(music.title).css("color","#FFF"))).click(function(){
                        $("#more-music").hide();
                        $(".player").show();
                        let url ="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q="+music.title+"song&maxResults=1&part=snippet&key="+youtubeAPIKey;
                        url=encodeURI(url);
                        $.get(url,function(response,status){
                          if (status=='success') {
                            $(".player iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+response.items[0].id.videoId).css("border", "0").css("width", "100%").css("height", "100vh");
                          }
                        });
                      })));
                    }
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          });
        });
```

RESULTADO:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!!

Comment: Faltou colocar o HTML.

Comment: Não tem html!
Simplesmente fiz append das divs no js.

Comment: Nas primeiras linhas da função existe: `response.artists[0].name` que não está definido em nenhum lugar, apenas depois no Ajax... isso resulta em erro.